# Dream for someone vs. Dream of someone

Tags: prepositions

> He had a dream for a family of his own.

vs.

> He had a dream of a family of his own.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dream) uses *about* and *of* as prepositions of choice for the noun *dream*. However, what I'm curious about is the *for* option in the given contexts. In my humble opinion, *dream for* has more emphasis on having the family in general, while *dream of* highlights the sort of family he was dreaming about. Can someone clarify this? Am I right, or is this just something my linguistically tortured mind made up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not recognise *dream for* as an idiomatic phrase in English.

I can understand you first example, and interpret it as *a dream of having a family of his own*, but it is not a collocation I recall ever having encountered before.

Looking at the iWeb corpus, it has 120 935 instances of *dream about*, 22 375 of *dream of*, and 9882 of *dream for*. But if I look at a selection of instances of *dream for*, I find that (on the first page of them, for example) only around 15 out of 100 use *for* in this sense (most of them are phrases like *a dream for me is to ...*)